# I linked a text to a page but it did not work

Tags: html

I linked a text in view page to a function but it did not work I do not know what is the problem. It worked in one page but note in another page I mean it did not work for two Previous pages

```
<a href="acontrol/show_sec">back</a>
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried

Comment: Please improve your question and show us what you have tried !

Comment: I read a question on a page about a function but it did not make sense I do not know what is the problem.  I understood a problem on one page but not this page I mean it did not make sense for this question.

Comment: Ah-ha!  Now we see your code!

Comment: Stackoverflow should have a validation for "It looks like you have hidden code in your question/answer"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need relative URLs that start from the root of your site: e.g.:

```
<a href="/acontrol/show_sec">back</a>
```